# How would I log a successful login

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

How would I log a successful login within the zfc-user module for the purpose of showing the user the last time he/she was successfully authorized?

I'm thinking a listener as zfcuser uses events, but are unable to figure it out

Comment: Afaik there is no event manager besides the form building and the event based auth adapter. I think the use case you have is a valid one but you need to PR ZfcUser in order to fulfill this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an authenticate event created in the module, which you can hook into (check example inside AdapterChainServiceFactory)

```
$chain = new AdapterChain;
$adapter = $serviceLocator->get('ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db');
$chain->getEventManager()->attach('authenticate', array($adapter, 'authenticate'));
```

You can hook onto the event, and then do some logging if the authenticate was a success, something like this:

```
// Attach onto the event somewhere...
$chain->getEventManager()->attach('authenticate', array($myObject, 'logAuthenticate'));

// MyObject
public function logAuthenticate(AuthEvent $e)
{
    // logging magic here..
}
```

Comment: This code does not work with the latest zfcuser version, here is my solution with ZfcUser 1.2.2:


    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $events = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

        // Handle login
        $events->attach('ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain', 'authenticate.success', function($e) {
            $userId = $e->getIdentity();
            // do some stuff
        });
    }

Answer (score 3):

Where the answer above didn't help me unfortunately, and where I continued to plow through and solved it -- my solution with varied mileage is here:

http://circlical.com/blog/2013/7/5/capturing-auth-events-with-zfcuser

Hope it helps another soul.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.